# relational database - synonyms table, how to deal with different forms of one word in search?

Tags: relational-database, synonym

I have a description of products - description is basically comma seperated string (like, `E124, water, tatrazin` etc.). I need to split this description into parts (by commas) and do some analyzes on each part (word) seperatly. Let us name this "`analysis of one words`" as "`algorithm`".

So, the algorithm basically is already implemented, however, it doens't understand all words. It has some "basic words" it understand and it doesn't understand synonyms and different forms of word. For instance, let us imaging that product consists of "`tatrazin`". The `algorithm` works well with "tatrazin", but `E102` also is "tatrazin" and "tatrazin" could have some other synonyms.

So, to fix this issue I wanted to create synonyms database and before sending words to "algorithm", I wanted to replace them with "known synonym".

I will use relational database and my table of synonyms would be like this:

`id, word_id, text, category` (category value is 'base' for words that are known and 'synonym' for unknown words)

```
1, 1, tatrazin, base
2, 1, E110, synonym
etc.
```

I think that this should work. And maybe "base" words would be stored in different table and "synonyms".

The only problem I do not know how to fix is that sometimes words also have different endings and other forms (for instance, plural or past form etc.). How this should be treated?

P.S. This is not in English, but another language, but in the future should support different languages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use stemming libraries like [stemmerNet](https://stemmersnet.codeplex.com/)

the stemming operation return each word to its base form.
it is supported in multiple languages.
 and for other meaning you can use [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) this is for english language and you can  find other dictionaries for other languages. 
 I hope this help